# PHP: Execute php code inside "php echo"

Tags: php, echo

I've got a php code where I created an echo:

```
<?php 
  my code...
  $line = "Hello world";
  echo "<li>php if (!empty($line)) { echo $line; }</li>";
?>
```

Unfortunately the `<li>` does not show Hello World.
As you can see here: http://codepad.org/QfcsINDy

Comment: why do you write php tag between php tag? it wont work

Comment: Without it does not work either: http://codepad.org/sDhGwZeO

Comment: do you want to print "echo"??

Comment: Looks like a XY problem, where Y could be solved using `eval()`. Being a XY problem, this is probably the wrong answer. Explain **what do you need to do**. *Why* do you want to echo the result of a PHP code fragment?

Comment: I need to this http://codepad.org/QfcsINDy - But as you can see the output is with the code

Comment: your code in above link is completely wrong, update you question with actual code in which you getting error, your question and code which is you provided in link are totally different

Comment: You simplified your problem past the point of getting a proper answer, unfortunately. I've updated your question with the code you provided in the comments which accurately highlights the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Check this

```
<?php 
 my code...
 ?>
<li><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>

<?php
?>
```

Or just

```
<?php 
 my code...
 echo "<li>Hello World</li>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write below code

```
<?php
 echo "<li>Hello World</li>";
?>
```

or

```
<li><?php echo "Hello World";?></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?></li>
```

only use php where necessary.
i am assuming you need to replace this 'Hello World' with a variable eventually thats why I used php, otherwise it would be like this.

```
<li>Hello World</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php 
 my code...

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li> Your Static Text Here </li>';
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

echo cannot be part of a php expression neither can it be used on a php expression. 
Just simply do

```
echo "<li>Hello World!</li>";
```

Or

```
print "<li>Hello World!</li>;
```

If what you are trying to achieve is have an expression between html tags please do

```
<li><?php echo "hello world" ?></li>
```

Or

```
<li><?= "hello world" ?></i>
```